Error running Rundeck with GCP managed SSL Content Security Policy directive
Rundeck Login page on HTTPS only (not HTTP) with the below error in the browser console
Refused to send form data to 'https://sub.domain.xxx/j_security_check' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".
Rundeck is deployed on an Ubuntu 22 GCP instance with an Unmanaged instance group connected to the load balancer, I've added a GCP-managed SSL certificate to the load balancer and it's provisioned successfully, the above error appears when trying to access the domain using HTTPS, what is the issue?

Could you try this? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5087#issuecomment-515485568

Have you tried checking this part of the rundeck docs which configures the file /etc/rundeck/profile.
There is also same discussion in the github regarding Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'.
